# console.log quit working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm not exactly sure when it started happening, roughly the last week or so, but Chrome no longer seems to print my console.log statements.  I've included a screenshot where on the console I type console.log('hello world'), and it simply prints undefined.  This is occuring on my Mac, Chrome Version 29.0.1547.65.  This exact same test on my Windows machine (Chrome version 29.01547.66 m) produces the output

```
hello world
undefined
```

I don't believe I have any filtering turned on or am doing anything differently than I was roughly a week ago.  Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

[image]

Comment: does this still happen? I have the same version, and I do get 'hello world' but also undefined after it

Comment: `console.log` returns `undefined`, it's normal behavior.

Comment: It says I have to wait 10 minutes to accept, I will once I can!

Comment: ohh i didn't know that (that you have to wait some time to accept an answer).. thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

click in the funnel and make sure you have `Logging` checked

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this fixed it for me.  I tried the 'Javascript' check, guess I should have tried Logging as well.  Not sure how these checks got turned off, but thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was Firebug Lite, which I thought I wasn't using at the moment (it was collapsed).

Open Firebug Lite and check off "Override Console Object".

Then the native Chrome console will receive messages again, and Firebug's console won't (like it couldn't print on both at the same time; go figure).

[image]

Comment: This was it for me.. Thanks! Driving me crazy